# Custom allocator for weak_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, allocator, memory-pool

From high CPU usage in `RtlpLowFragHeapAllocFromContext()` I am making a guess that `std::weak_ptr()` that I use frequently (calling `.lock()` on it) should be the culprit that doesn't use the internal efficient memory pool, but rather resorts to `malloc()`/`free()`/`new`/`delete` guys.

Is there a way to specify custom allocator for an `std::weak_ptr`? If yes, how? If no, why?

UPDATE: uploading the profiler snapshot
[image: Profiler Snapshot]

Comment: Do you have any evidence of that? As far as I know, getting a shared_ptr from a weak_ptr shouldn't do anything but a stack allocation for the new shared_ptr. Both use the same existing control block.

Comment: Better than guessing is profiling. Creating shared from weak really shouldn't allocate.

Comment: Unfortunately, the profiler (AMD uProf) doesn't seem to record call stacks to say for sure on who is using the heap. I'll attach a screenshot of what I have.

Comment: might wanna have a look at c++17 memory resources using polymorphic allocator for shared_ptr

Comment: @SergeRogatch You can try some special heap profiler such as Heaptrack.

Answer (score 3):

`weak_ptr` does not allocate memory, nor do any of its operations (which are all `noexcept`). It does its job based on allocations which are part of any `shared_ptr`'s control block. You can customize `shared_ptr`'s control block allocation behavior, but that's got nothing to do with `weak_ptr` itself.